# NGINX localhost upstream configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am running multi services app orchestrated by docker-compose and for testing purposes I want to run it on localhost (MacOS).

With this NGINX configuration:

```
upstream fe {
    server fe:3000;
}

upstream be {
    server be:4000;
}

server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://fe;
    }

    location /api/ {
       proxy_pass http://be;
    }
}
```

I am able to get FE in browser from `http://localhost/` and BE from `http://localhost/api/` as expected.

**Issue is that FE refusing communicate with BE with this error:**

`Error: Network error: request to http://localhost/api/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

(It's NEXT.JS FE with NODE/EXPRESS/APOLLO-GQL BE)

Note: I need to upstream BE, because I need to download files from email directly with URL.

**Am I missing some NGINX headers, DNS configuration etc.?**

Thanks in an advance!

Comment: What code is making the network call that produces that error?  Is the `fe` container making the call directly, or is it code that ultimately runs in the browser?

Comment: It's code inside `fe` container, I have apolloClient wrapping all <App/> and initial call to BE is on SS of Next.js. In production (remote VPS) it works, problem is on localhost only.

Comment: If it's code inside the `fe` container, `localhost` is the `fe` container, and you need to use the other container name `be` as a host name.  If it's code in the browser, `localhost` is the machine running the browser, and the Docker-internal host names aren't visible.

Comment: If I set host to `be` from `fe` not via reverse proxy but directly like `http://be:4000` I am able to load initial state of app properly from `http://localhost` (not getting the error above), however on next call from browser  I gets `POST http://be:4000/api/graphql net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial call to Apollo is from Next.js (FE container) 'server side', that means BE needs to be addressed to docker network (it cannot be localhost, because for this call is localhost FE container itself). In my case is that call to process.env.BE that is set to `http://be:4000`.

However for other calls (sending login request from browser) is docker network unknown (calling it from localhost that has no access to docker network) that mean you have to address `localhost/api/graphql`.

I am able to achieve that functionality just with a small change in my FE httpLink -  apollo connecting function:

```
uri: isBrowser ? `/api/graphql` : `${process.env.BE}/api/graphql`
```

NGINX config is the same as above.

**NOTE: This needs to be handle only on local environment, on remote server it work fine without this 'hack' and address is always `domain.com/api/graphql`.**